# How to make vim syntax highlight quoted text in .tex file?

Tags: vim, latex, syntax-highlighting

In emacs, the text quoted between `` and '' are highlighted as green. It comes in handy sometimes. I believe should be possible to also do it in latex. But I don't know how.

I checked the tex.vim in `$RUNTIME/syntax` folder. It appeared to me that the closest thing related to such quotes are `texString`, `texStyleStatement`, which are both highlighted by default. But in my file between the quotes are unhighlighted text. Were I mistaken? Is it something else that represents the quoted text? Or is it not defined in tex.vim?

Answer (score 0):

In my custom VIM syntax file I have:

```
syntax region MyString start="'" end="'"
highlight link MyString String
```

Maybe that will work for you?

Comment: No, it didn't. I used `syntax region DoubleQuote start="\`\`" end="''"`, and linked `DoubleQuote` to `String` like you suggested. It stilll didn't highlight quotes.